# MobileFirst QA for Bluemix component does not appear to work

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-qa

I am using MobileFirst Platform 6.3 with Eclipse Luna. I have downloaded the MobileFirst QA for Bluemix component (MQA-1.9.19-saas.wlc) file and confirmed that in Eclipse the Download Folder for the Templates and Components is /User/KenAtIBM/IBM/Templates and that indeed the SDK is in that folder.

When I attempt to Add/Remove Application Components I get the following in the console:

> [2014-12-17 10:59:48]             Component = MQA-1.9.19-saas.wlc
>   [2014-12-17 10:59:48]             Found component.wcp
>   [2014-12-17 10:59:48]             Found Image
>   [2014-12-17 10:59:48]             imagePath
>   =/var/folders/vz/10zz3f2s46v3940lv5wvpn2c0000gn/T/MQAlogo-small2578766252585890320.png

The problem is that there is no component listed (see attached screen shot).

I have been following the instructions with no success as of yet. So my question is, what am I missing?

I have tried rename the file to have a zip extension, same out come as above.
I have tried un-archiving the zip, no success.
I have restarted eclipse numerous times and even went so far as to reboot, still nothing.

Is the SDK that is downloaded from here compatible with MobileFirst Platform?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I hit save before adding the picture. It is there now, but really has no impact on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** you should play with the column resizer rather than the window size. After doing that, the entry will appear.

[image]

I see you are using Eclipse Luna on Mac OS X  10.10.x Yosemite.

There is an OS X bug that does something wrong with tables - try to play with the size of the window containing the table and then scroll in it, the component should probably then show up.

Comment: You are correct that I am using Eclipse Luna on Yosemite. However your suggestion does not work as resizing the window does not affect the size of the table.

Comment: Then answer the rest of the questions in my comment.

Comment: Ah, what questions? Mac Yosemite 10.10.1? Or did miss something?

Comment: Here refers to: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSJML5_6.0.0/com.ibm.mqa.uau.saas.doc/topics/c_worklight_sdk.html

Comment: Instructions are http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSJML5_6.0.0/com.ibm.mqa.uau.saas.doc/topics/t_install_worklight_libs.html

Comment: Idan. Thank you for your response, I will continue to research a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, the first row of the Add Component is hidden in the table.  Simply scroll down and you will see it.

For me, I have 4 templates, but I can only see 3 of them when the dialog starts.  I have to scroll down inside that table to see the first row.

And I have tested the MQA on BlueMix with MFP 6.3.  It works fine.  I can submit my screenshot to the bluemix cloud.

Comment: JFJF. What version of eclipse are you using? Also what JDK/JRE are you using? Thank You for the reply.

Comment: My Mac is on 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1. Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 4.4.1.20140925-1820. MFP 6.3.0.00-20141218-1823. Note that I was testing with the "QA_MODE". I did not try the production mode. I can submit screenshot with this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify things, *MobileFirst Quality Assurance for Bluemix* does work together with *MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3*

I was able to successfully instrument a hybrid app with the JavaScript SDK http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSJML5_6.0.0/com.ibm.mqa.uau.saas.doc/topics/c_worklight_sdk.html, and start sessions in both pre-production and production modes. I've used the following configuration:

- Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers   4.4.1.20140925-1820
- IBM MobileFirst Platform 6.3.0.00-20141218-1823
- Javascript SDK for Worklight 1.9.19
- Windows 7 64-bit SP1

It seems that the problem here is with the 'JavaScript SDK' not showing up in the table to 'add/remove application components' when MFP 6.3 is running on Mac OS X Yosemite